# Distance between subsets of metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Here is a picture of the question, background information, and my attempt/thoughts on the problem.

[image]

My main concern, is my understanding of the distance function given.  I'm not sure how to calculate the distance between two subsets of the metric space using this distance.  In particular the inf, or greatest lower bound part of the definition confuses me.  Some examples would really help me out.
Also, I'm not sure if the set I picked does indeed define a metric space and how to show it formally using the 3 axioms of a metric space.

Thank you!!

Comment: A metric space is just a set $X$ with a metric $d: X \times X \to [0, +\infty)$ satisfying some properties. It can be easily seen that any subset $Y$ of $X$ is a metric space if we consider $d|_{Y \times Y}$.

Comment: I think you can show that for each $x \in \Bbb{R}$, $d(C,D) \leq d(C,x) + d(D,x) $, and $d(C,0) = d(D, 0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks.  can you give me a few examples calculating distance between two sets using the distance function given.  Also, is my answer correct that the distance between (-1,0) and (0,1) is 0.

Comment: Indeed, this $d$ as a distance between sets is a *pseudometric*. It satisfies triangle inequality and symmetry, but the distance between distinct (infact disjoint) sets can be zero, as you have shown correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance $d(C,D)$ is defined to be the infimum of the set $\{d(c,d) \mid c\in C,\,d\in D\}$, which is just the set of all possible distances between elements of $C$ and elements of $D$.

For your particular example, it is true that $d((-1,0),(0,1))=0$. To see this note that
$$
\{d(x,y) \mid x\in(-1,0),y\in(0,1)\}=(0,2)
$$
and the infimum of this set is $0$.

Alternatively we can argue that for each $\varepsilon>0$, we have $-\varepsilon/2\in(-1,0)$ and $\varepsilon/2\in (0,1)$ so that
$$
d((-1,0),(0,1)) \le d(-\varepsilon/2,\varepsilon/2) = \varepsilon.
$$
Since $d((-1,0),(0,1))\le \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$, we conclude that it is $0$.

Comment: Thank you.  Very clear explanation.  So would ((-1,1), d) define a metric space?

Comment: @BOB Yes, assuming by $d$ you mean the usual distance $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. (Which is what I assumed in the answer above.)

Comment: If so, how would I formally prove this.  I know that the question just asks to give an example, but for my own understanding, I would like to prove this.  Thanks!

Comment: By d, I mean the d defined using the infimum inf d(c,d).  Would this be a metric space?

Comment: @BOB Oh. So you mean to ask if $(\mathcal{P}((-1,1)),d)$ is a metric space, where $\mathcal{P}((-1,1))$ is the set of all subsets of $(-1,1)$. The answer to this is no. This is because there are two distinct elements whose distance is $0$.

Comment: So what would be an example of a metric space using this d.

Comment: @BOB First you need to show that this $d$ satisfies symmetry, nonnegatiivity, and the triangle inequality. If it does, then the only barrier to finding an appropriate space would be one in which there are no distinct sets whose distance is $0$. Since any two sets with nontrivial intersection will have a distance of $0$, this would require that there are no distinct sets with nontrivial intersection. This means that your original metric space cannot contain more than $2$ elements.

Comment: @BOB So this sort of thing doesn't happen in practice. Thus the use of the word "distance" in describing $d(C,D)$ is not in the technical sense of a distance on a metric space, since for this to be true your space would have to be very special (and quite trivial).

Comment: I don't mean to ask if the power set or the set of all subsets  of (-1,1)  is defined as a metric space with the given d, my apologies.  I'm asking if the d given satisfies the set of axioms of a metric space for the set, or interval (-1,1)

Comment: @BOB No it doesn't. It doesn't satisfy the most basic axiom: it isn't defined for the right elements. A metric $\rho$ on a set $X$ is a function $\rho:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ with special properties (nonnegativity, symmetry, triangle inequality, and $\rho(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$). In your case, $d$ is not a function on $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$. It's a function on $\mathcal{P}((-1,1))\times\mathcal{P}((-1,1))$. In other words, it acts on subsets of $(-1,1)$, not on elements of $(-1,1)$.

Comment: I understand now.  Could you give me an example of a metric space then using d.  Thanks.

Comment: would (R, d) be a metric space? where R represents the real numbers

Comment: @BOB If by $d$ you mean the usual distance $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, then yes. If you mean the one in your question which is about measuring the "distance" between subsets of a metric space, then I think you are misunderstanding my replies if you still think that's possible.

Comment: I see, my apologies for not understanding.

Comment: So is it even possible to find a metric space using the d, which is measuring the distance between subsets?

Comment: @BOB No it's okay! The thing is that you need to start with a metric space to even define $d$. When the question says "Find an example of a metric space...", it means the one you start with - namely $(-1,1)$ with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Once you have that metric space, you are asked to find two disjoint subsets whose "distance" is $0$. You did just that with $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. The $d$ defined between sets using the infimum is not meant to be a metric of its own metric space. It's just a way to measure the "distance" between subsets of an existing metric space.

Comment: Got it! I think I misunderstood the question given.  So ((-1,1), with d being the usual metric |x-y|) is a metric space.  and then once I have this metric space, I use  the infimum distance to find the distance between (-1,0) and (0,1), two disjoint subjects of (-1,1).  Is this correct?  Thanks!

Comment: @BOB Exactly!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need it, but another idea is the following:

First, consider $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ and prove that the graph of a continuous function $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $Gr(f)=\{(x,f(x)):x\in E\}$

Now take $E=\mathbb{R}^+$ , $f(x)=\frac{1}{x},$  $g(x)=0$, and check that the distance between those graphs is $0$ but their intersection is empty.